# How to compile ffmpeg 5 with x86_64 and ARM64 support

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm building ffmpeg version 5.0.1 from source, but for some reason I don't get it to cross-compile against aarch64 as I want to run ffmpeg on a Khadas VIM4 which is a ARMv8 CPU, to be specific the CPU is an Amlogic A311D2 with non-free codecs..

To build ffmpeg from source, I have setup a build-suite put together from various sources which currently works fine with x86_64 and can be obtained here: https://github.com/venomone/ffmpeg_build_suite

*Simply run trigger.sh from the terminal, make sure docker is installed on your host if you are interested. The script will output ffprobe and ffmpeg in a folder called /build*

From my understanding, the ffmpeg configuration part must get extended by the following lines:

```
--enable-cross-compile \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm64 \
--cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- \
--enable-shared \
```

But even with these settings, I'm running into the following error:

```
#11 938.3 aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc is unable to create an executable file.
#11 938.3 C compiler test failed.
```

Is somebody able to provide me a hint, what might be the problem here?

Comment: Yes, this is frustrating. I can recommend you take a look at `ffbuild/config.log` file. At the end of this file, there are more meaningful messages about why it fails.

Comment: It could simply be that `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` package needs to be installed